# VBA in Visio: SelectionChanged Event Not Firing to Bring Shape to Front

Tags: vba, event-handling, visio

I've been working with VBA v7.1 in Microsoft Visio 16 to bring a selected shape to the front layer when it is selected. I've set up an event handler to trigger the SelectionChanged event but haven't had any success.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
Public MyEvents As New MyVisioEvents

Sub InitializeEvents()
    Set MyEvents.vApp = Visio.Application
End Sub

Public WithEvents vApp As Visio.Application

Private Sub vApp_SelectionChanged(ByVal Selection As IVSelection)
    If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
        If Selection.Count > 0 Then
            Dim shape As Visio.shape
            Set shape = Selection.Item(1)
            shape.BringToFront
            Debug.Print "Shape moved to front: " & shape.Name
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Ultimately I want to set this up so InitializeEvents is called when the Visio document is opened; however, first, I want the code to work when I execute InitializeEvents manually.  I'm getting the infamous error: "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name." I see this error in many other VBA posts but have not been able to solve my specific case. Here are the debugging steps I've tried. Nothing has helped so far. I keep getting the same error.

1. I checked the event signature to make sure that the vApp_SelectionChanged subroutine matches the expected signature for Visio's SelectionChanged event. It does.
2. The code I posted above is all in one module; however, I tried splitting the event definition and its handler in separate modules in case that matters. This didn't help.
3. I tried Debug > Compile VBAProject, and this raises the compile time error mentioned above. I also used Run > Reset to clear any existing objects from memory. No help.
4. I tried the code in a fresh Visio document to rule out any possible corruption issues with the actual drawing document. No help.
5. I inserted the code shown below into the "ThisDocument" code window to see if running InitializeEvents automatically when I open the drawing has any effect. I then closed and reopened the drawing. The code attempted to run but produced the same compile time error mentioned above.

```
Private Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal doc As IVDocument)
    InitializeEvents
End Sub
```

6. Just to be sure the code isn't somehow running I added the debug print statement shown below and tried step 5 again. The debug print statement did not execute. Instead, I got the same compile time error as in all other attempts.

```
Private Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal doc As IVDocument)
    Debug.Print "Document opened and InitializeEvents is running."
    InitializeEvents
End Sub
```

7. Finally, I tried the Visio repair option built into Windows 10. This seems to have re-installed Visio. I'm using Visio 2016 Professional and had to dig up my license key for this. The "repair process" completed successfully. I then repeated all the steps above. Unfortunately, nothing changed.

Comment: `Public MyEvents As New MyVisioEvents` what is it?

Comment: SelectionChanged has WINDOW as an argument, not SELECTION (refer to surrogate's code below). You can always add your even handlers using the dropdown boxes at the top of the code window, to ensure you have correct parameter types.

Comment: As far as I know, global variables need to be declared at the top of the file. so `vApp` declaration will need to be moved up in addition to the other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

At my side this code works!

```
Public WithEvents vApp As Visio.Application

Sub InitializeEvents()
    Set vApp = Visio.Application
End Sub
   
Private Sub vApp_SelectionChanged(ByVal Window As IVWindow)
Dim sl As Selection
Set sl = Window.Selection
    If Not sl Is Nothing Then
        If sl.Count > 0 Then
            Dim shape As Visio.shape
            Set shape = sl.Item(1)
            shape.BringToFront
            Debug.Print "Shape moved to front: " & shape.Name
        End If
    End If
Set sl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please look at this demo
[image: Demo]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: when will `sl = Nothing`?

Comment: You are right! I forgot about this)